I want specific product url in shopify. now it is coming with product id
I am new to Shopify and currently building a shopping site. Each product has multiple variants (e.g., blue, black). On the home page, the product URLs appear without an ID, but when I select any variant, the URL includes an ID.
For example, the current URL looks like this:
https://nickron-site.myshopify.com/products/pluto-black-womens-sneakers?variant=46592499384552
But I want it to be:
https://nickron-site.myshopify.com/products/pluto-black-womens-sneakers-black.
I’ve tried updating some files and writing code to achieve this, but it’s still not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Could you please share your store password? I can't access the links as they're password protected.
If I understand, you don't want to URL to update on variant change, is this correct?
